# IsValidOn and ForEach

Tags: c#

I apologize in advance... I'm new to C# and am trying to teach myself (badly)!

I've been set a number of tasks to decipher some code and explain what it's doing, but on these three pieces I'm really struggling - I only have the code detailed - nothing else to put it onto context... otherwise I think I'd be fine.

```
if (HasMark && !MarkReference.Entity.IsValidOn(DateSignedUp.Value)) {
 LogError(PersonMessages.MarkNotValidOnDateSignedUp(DateSignedUp));
```

My thought:
If HasMark variable is true and the DateSignedUp value is false, then call the PersonMessages error and specify the DateSigned up value.

```
if (From.HasValue && From.Value<Session.Current.VirtualNow) logError(PersonNonMessages.PastHoliday);
```

My thought: If From is true and From equals (whatever) "Session.Current.VirtualNow" is, through up the PersonNonMessages.PastHoliday error.

```
if (pastAuditLogs != null) pastAuditLogs.ForEach(x => x.AuditLogs = auditLogs);
```

My thought: If pastAuditLogs isn't null, for each entry in the pastAuditLog, loop through and find the latest entry for each.

Could anyone please advise on if any of my assumptions above are correct, or if I'm even close to understanding the code?
Apologies it's so vague - if there was any other supporting code or background scenario it'd be 10x easier to understand!

Many thanks

Comment: You have 'thoughts' but we expect questions here. What are you actually asking?   And preferably ask 1 question per Question.

Comment: My guess would be that `IsValidOn(SomeDate)` means "is this thing valid on the given date?", not "some variable is `false`. The `From` variable is not evaluated to be `true` or `false`, the code checks whether the variable_has a value_ and if so, whether that value is smaller than some other value.

Comment: With respect, fellow SO folks, let's not come down TOO hard on this guy thrown into the deep end of code maintenance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Visual Studio, correct?

You can right click on any symbol (like `HasMark`) and then choose Show Definition.  Then, you can see a white arrow in a blue circle at the upper left of your pane, that takes you back to where you were. This is an incredibly handy feature for code archaelogy.

Also, if you hover your cursor over code you often get a bit of explanation in a tooltop.

Let's tear apart this hunk of code bit by bit...

```
if (HasMark && !MarkReference.Entity.IsValidOn(DateSignedUp.Value)) {
   LogError(PersonMessages.MarkNotValidOnDateSignedUp(DateSignedUp));
}
```

It means...

1. If `HasMark` is true....
2. Call the boolean-valued function `MarkReference.Entity.IsValidOn()` ...
3. Passing the value  `DateSignedUp.Value`
4. If that function returns false (`!`)  ...
5. Call the function `PersonMessages.MarkNotValidOnDateSignedUp()` ...
6. Passing the value `DateSignedUp` ...
7. and pass the returned value to the function `LogError()`.

The `&&` operator won't perform step 2 above if `HasMark` is false.

The order I've shown here is important.  In this bit of code, the second line seems to have the side effect of marking something not valid.  But maybe that `MarkNotValidOnDateSignedUp()` method just looks up some message to toss into `LogError()`.

To know exactly what all this stuff means isn't possible without having your code base present.  That's what you use Show Definition to do.

`<CTRL><SHIFT><F>` activates a Find All function. That's handy too.

Can you run this stuff in the debugger?  If so, step through it with Step Into  and see what it does.

*Pro tip:* There's an addon package to Visual Studio called Resharper. It helps with this kind of code archaelogy. They have a free evaluation and sell personal copies for short money.

Comment: I don't have any stake in Resharper except as a user.